# how to read the file contents using javascript for ie8?

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer-8

I have file path, how to read the file contents using javascript for ie8?
FileReader is not supported in ie8.

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions, or even just http://www.google.com?